# why this jquery code works under opera only and not under firefox and chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox, opera

simple and start of a new interface:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css" />
    <script src="./javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var color = $('#title_buttom').css('background-color');
            $('.title_all').mouseover(function(){
                var styles = {
                backgroundColor : '#FF0C55'};
                $('#title_buttom').css( styles );
            });
            $('.title_all').mouseout(function(){
                $('#title_buttom').css('background-color',color);
            });
        });​
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='all_div'>
        <div id='master'>
            <div id='title_top'>
                <div id='title_home' class='title_all'>Home</div>
                <div id='title_info' class='title_all'>Info</div>
                <div id='title_project' class='title_all'>Projects</div>
                <div id='title_contectus' class='title_all'>Contect us</div>
            </div>
            <div id='title_buttom'></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
    </html>
```

for same reason i don't know why only the opera browser can use this code while the firefox and the chrome can't. why is that?

[link to the css file](http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=5144)

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9dtrd/1/

Comment: try $('.title_all').on('mouseout',function(){
                $('#title_buttom').css('background-color',color);
            });  i added a answere... guess this should work... comment my post please if it works fine for you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var color = $('#title_buttom').css('background-color');
    $('.title_all').on('mouseover',function () {
        var styles = {
            backgroundColor: '#FF0C55'
        };
        $('#title_buttom').css(styles);
    });
    $('.title_all').on('mouseout',function () {
        $('#title_buttom').css('background-color', color);
    });
});
```

may you try this here to check if there is a problem using backgroundColor instead of background-color in your styles object.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
    {
    var color = $('#title_buttom').css('background-color');

    $('.title_all').on('mouseover',function () 
        {
            $('#title_buttom').css('background-color','#FF0C55');
        });

    $('.title_all').on('mouseout',function () 
    {
        $('#title_buttom').css('background-color', color);
    });
});
```

Comment: the opera browser works fine with your addition/change but the firefox and the chrome browser do noting as with my code.

Comment: this is acualy kinda strange ^^ what jquery version do you use ? and if you run fiddle (like @Arun P Johny sayed), does this still happen ?

Comment: i know it is kinda strange. i'm using <script src="./javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> i even tried to upload the folder to my real site and the browsers: firefox and chrome are still doing that problem and the opera is fine. tried with my smartphone and other pc's and the firefox and the chrome don't show the jquery effect and the opera do. something in the code is wrong but i don't know what.

Comment: i don't use php yet in this template, it is only the start of this template, so i have here only the client site right now.

Comment: sorry... i just mixed this answere with an other question :D could you try to use 1.10.1 ? because fiddle says that 1.10.1 is the highest they have in fiddle atm

Comment: i  checked that with alert() function and inside the mouseover function and found that the forefox and chrome didn't present at all the alert. meaning the 'mouseover' event isn't been used at all in my firefox and chrome.

Comment: i tried now with jquery-1.10.1.min.js Dwza as well but same result.    "#title_buttom" have to change when the mouse in over ".title_all" and then rechange again after the mouse is not over ".title_all".

Comment: Would you explain why this answers the question?  Code only answers disturb me.

Comment: i posted the code to turn some statements in his code and i can not do this in a comment... in the end it works here on chrome and firefox... but doesn't work for him... only on opera so i can't locate to problem... only if he have old browsers :)